# Scapegoat search function

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I inserted 30000 random numbers into a scapegoat tree. I have a counter to keep track of comparisons my insertions and searches make. I tried to search for number 3337, it wasn't found but the tracker said it took nearly 6 million comparisons to make that assumption which is pretty far from the O(logn) complexity.
Here is my search function

```
/* Functions to search for an element */
        bool search(int val)
        {
            return search(root, val);
        }

        /* Function to search for an element recursively */
        bool search(SGTNode *r, int val)
        {
            bool found = false;
            while ((r != NULL) && !found)
            {
                cnt++;
                cnt++;
                int rval = r->value;
                if (val < rval){
                    cnt++;
                    r = r->left;
                }
                else if (val > rval){
                    cnt++;
                    cnt++;
                    r = r->right;
                }
                else
                {
                    cnt++;
                    cnt++;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                found = search(r, val);
            }
            cnt++;
            cnt++;
            return found;
        }
```

I am 100% sure that the cnt counter was 0 before search was called. If you need more of my code feel free to ask.

Comment: What is purpose of that `while` loop? Looks like you are mixing recursive and iterative approaches.

Comment: I changed that to an if and indeed my counts fell off dramatically

Comment: Wrote you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing recursive and iterative approaches to a binary search. So pick one:

**Iterative approach (pick me)**:

```
bool search(SGTNode *r, int val)
{
    while (r)
    {
        int rval = r->value;
        if (val < rval)
            r = r->left;
        else if (val > rval)
            r = r->right;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Recursive approach (don't pick me, I just look nicer):**

```
bool search(SGTNode *r, int val)
{
    if(!r) // End the recursion if an element is not found
        return false;

    int rval = r->value;
    if (val < rval)
        return search(r->left,val);
    else if (val > rval)
        return search(r->right)
    else // Ends the recursion if an element is found
        return true;
}
```

Add `counters` as you see fit.